# Realm Migration: Migrating objects to another

Tags: swift, database, migration, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I've added a new Model object to my realm objects and I am trying to move data from my old realm object properties to this new object.

In the old Schema, I have the following:

```
class Item: Object {
    @objc dynamic var image = ""
    @objc dynamic var coverImage = ""
    @objc dynamic var video = ""
}
```

In the new schema, I've added a new property called **media**
so now it's looking this this

```
class Item: Object {
    @objc dynamic var image = ""
    @objc dynamic var coverImage = ""
    @objc dynamic var video = ""

    @objc dynamic var media: Media?
}
```

**I've also added this new Model object:**

```
class Media: Object {

    @objc dynamic var fullImage = ""
    @objc dynamic var thumbnailImage = ""
    @objc dynamic var video = ""

    var item = LinkingObjects(fromType: Item.self, property: "media")
}
```

My goal is to move the data from the old **Item** objects to the new **Media** objects.

I was trying to do something like this, but I don't know how to migrate that linking object, any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
 Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 1,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {

                // enumerate first object
                migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Item.className()) { oldItem, newItem in

                    let image = oldItem?["image"] as! String
                    let coverImage = oldItem?["coverImage"] as! String
                    let video = oldItem?["video"] as! String

                    //migrate second object
                    migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Media.className(), { (oldMedia, newMedia) in

                    })
                }
            }
    })
```

Comment: Are you saying you are *replacing* the Item object with the Media object? If so, the field names are different and your Media object links back to the Item object so if the Item object is removed, that will be a problem. Additionally, your Media object doesn't have a coverImage property etc. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Jay No, I am not replacing Item object with Media object, I added a new property "media" in the Item object, which is a reference to the Media object. I Want to use the Media object to store "Image" "video" etc and separate them from the Item object. When users update the app, I want to transfer the values from the Item objects to the new Media objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything with `LinkingObjects`, realm calculates those automatically when you query them.

All you'll need to do in your migration is set `media` to be a new `Media` object with the values you already have.

Other notes:

- The second `enumerateObjects` isn't needed.
- You can remove `image`, `coverImage`, and `video` from `Item` since you're moving those value to `Media`

---

Edit: This is what you would need to have in your migration.

```swift
let media = Media()
media.fullImage = oldItem?["image"] as! String
media.thumbnailImage = oldItem?["coverImage"] as! String
media.video = oldItem?["video"] as! String

newItem?["media"] = media
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I am very new to this and for some reason, I cannot wrap my mind around what you suggested. Would you mind showing me in code? Thank you.

Comment: Which part aren't you clear on? I've add an example of how you could do it in the migration.

Comment: I've added this code to the migration and it deleted all my data from the database.

Comment: Hey Craig, thank you for your help. You've helped me solve my issues, but there are 2 correct answers, you and Jay below. I don't know which one to accept.

Comment: @IamWayne Glad your issue was resolved. If both answers helped, upvote them both and then accept this one - after the edit it was a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

When adding objects to a project, the migration is super simple. In this case you're not changing or adding data to existing or new properties so it's even easier.

All that needs to be done is to increment the schemaVersion and implement your migration block. Suppose the prior version was 1, increment that to 2.

```
let config = Realm.Configuration (
    schemaVersion: 2,
    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        //nothing to do here since we not altering any data
})
```

Realm already knows your Object has data and that data will persist as it's not being altered. All of the Item objects will have the new media property added and linked to the new Media object.

See [Local Migrations](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations) for more examples. The Updating values section is when you want to actually manipulate the existing data

**Edit:**

We now have a bit more information and what the OP is trying to do is to copy data from an existing object to a new object and then create a relationship between the objects. Here's the code that would do that.

The initial object is Item and the new object is Media. For this example I am copying the data in a Item property `image` to the Media property `fullImage`

```
let config = Realm.Configuration (
    schemaVersion: 1,
    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Item.className() ) { oldObject, newObject in
            let image = oldObject!["image"] as! String
            let media = Media()
            media.fullImage = image
            newObject!["media"] = media
        }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I added a new property in the Item object called "media". The app crashes, because migration is needed on the new Item.media property. I want to transfer my data from the Item object to the new Media object.

Comment: @IamWayne I duplicated your objects and code and ran the project and it works correctly. Adding a property will not require you to 'transfer your data'. But your comment doesn't match the code in the question; in the code you are simply adding a property but not populating it with any data. Your comment here say you want to *transfer my data*. Can you clarify what that means as nothing in your code populates the Media object with any data.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am a new trying to learn realm.  Whenever users update the app I would like the data that's already stored with the Item properties "image", "coverImage" etc. To be stored with the new Media properties "fullImage", "thumbnailImage" etc. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @IamWayne Still a little confused so let me repeat this back. You have Item objects currently in your database. You are adding a new Media object to your database and creating a relationship between the Item object and Media Object. During the migration you want to copy the data that exists in the Item Object and Populate the properties in the Media object, therefore creating duplicate data as it would then exist in both Item and Media. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I would delete those properties from the Item object, so the data will be available on the Media objects after migration. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for your help.

Comment: @IamWayne, Ok, I gotcha - check out the edited answer. I tested it to make sure and it works correctly.

Comment: Jay, thank you for your help. You helped solved my issues, but there are 2 correct answers, you Craig above I don't know which one to accept.